# How to use token in Global: PHP field

Tags: views

In View, there is this field called "Global: PHP". I wonder how I can use token in this field in Drupal 7.  I can easily use token in "Global: Custom text" but not in "Global: PHP"

Answer (score 2):

In a "Global: Custom Text" you will see a number of tokens listed under "Replacement patterns", such as [title], [php] (referring to a "Global: PHP" field), [nothing] (referring to another "Global: Custom Text" field), ...

These tokens (or replacement patterns), are not listed when working with a "Global: PHP" field, you can only see a list of "Available variables", and if you put a token in the "Output code" textarea, it does not get replaced.

However, there is a way to access these tokens in "Global: PHP" fields. For example, if you are trying to access the [nothing] token, put the following code in the "Output code" textarea (not in the "Value code" textarea):

```
<?php
$static = $view->display_handler->get_handlers('field');
echo $static['nothing']->last_render;
?>
```

Solution found here: https://www.drupal.org/node/507012#comment-3410296

Except it was for Drupal 6, so they used `$this->view`. In Drupal 7, you have to use `$view`.

Answer (score 1):

The tokens stand in for values from, say, the $node object for example. So if you're using php instead of using a token like `[title]` you'd call it with `$node->title` or the equivalent. If you don't know what variables are available to you, try the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel/) to help you navigate those objects and arrays.

Comment: helpful tips! Thanks! In View got to use $data object instead. Many more to explore :)

Answer (score 0):

This file is from [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module.
It gives the ability to use raw PHP field as a normal field so you can process the results in real time. It makes other fields available as php variables. You can of course use tokens in Custom text fields. But you can't process them (e.g You can't show sum of 2 tokens using a custom text field). Views PHP solves this by giving you a place to enter the PHP code.

You can use $data *object* to access data of the *current field* and the *current view*. You can use a code like below to see all avail. variables.

```
<?php
print '<pre>'.print_r($data, TRUE).'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Instead of using `print_r()` if you install the Devel module and use `dsm()` instead you'll get a much more navigable version of your array or object.

Comment: Right, using Devel is good indeed. But seems there is detail value I didn't see in Devel, rather it shows in print_r(). I encountered once.

Comment: I wonder what's the main different between using dsm() and krumo() ?

Comment: dsm() sets a Drupal message soit will not mes up any of the styling (dsm = "devel set message"). 
krumo() will issue a print of the variable's krumo display so most likely that it will appear on top of your site and will cause "cannot modify headers" warning